# Rubik's Cube Permutations

Tags: permutations, rubiks-cube

I know the formula for finding the number of permutations of the $3$x$3$ cube, which is $$\frac{8! \times 3^8 \times 12! \times 2^{12}}{12}$$

But why must the division by $12$ be a part of the formula? From looking it up I know it has to do with some of the positions being impossible without disassembling the cube, but why specifically division by $12$ and not another number?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but if your formula is correct you can remove the division by 12 and make it 11! on the numerator instead of 12!

Comment: @Ninja_Coder Very true! This format was just how I was introduced to it is all. You could remove the fraction a few ways, yours of which being what I think is most convenient. Another option is to take one power of $3$ and two powers of $2$ away.